# How to set RestSharp's CultureInfo used on request serialization?

Tags: c#, serialization, restsharp

I have a RestRequest instance where there is a parameter with a double value, when the parameter has any decimal value, like 1000.11, the request fail with "The request is invalid".

This happens because our Web API is expecting a value in en-US culture code format to deserialize, aka "1000.11", but RestSharp is sending "1000,11".

I know that I can change the client current thread's CultureInfo to resolve this, but I want a little better solution.

The question is: **there is any way to config RestSharp (RestClient or RestRequest) to use only "en-US" culture code to serialize the request paremeters?**

Answer (score 2):

The author of the project fixed this problem 14 days ago.  He [updated XmlSerializer.cs](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commit/12d28ddc98239c24707cd3018ac32a8ee8e805d0) and added the SerializeNumber() method.  It now uses:

```
...
return (Convert.ToDouble(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).
    ToString("r", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Which should fix your problem, InvariantCulture formats floating point values with the period.

Just pull the last update of the project from Github.

Comment: I'm pretty sure github is up and running, I just used it 5 minutes ago.